# Webkit (Safari/Chrome) renders margin with percentage not accurate on floating elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, css-float

I have two container that float and they should take up 100% width of the parent element.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box half">2</div>
<div class="box half">2</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
}

body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

body {
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    float: left;    
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.box.half {
    width: 49.2%;
    margin-right: 1.6%; 
}

.box.half + .box.half {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

In Firefox this works just fine, but Chrome and Safari mess it up. It works on some screen sizes (looks like when the resulting sizes are integers) but not on all. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

[image]

Have a look in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sntqazp/).

Comment: First suggestion is to set the body width to a percent value as well, it may change something on the responsive behave

Comment: @user3760661 Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't affect the behavior. I also need to set a min and max width using pixels on the parent element, so I actually need a solution that works on all possible sizes.

Comment: do you mind explain the issue a bit more? thanks

Comment: @user3760661 Of course. I've added an image how it looks. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: well, i've just tested this on firefox, chrome and IE, on various screen sizes, and i've never seen that gap.
Maybe you can try adding a relative position to the parent div, an absolute to the floating one with negative offset so that they are below the parent. and then align with left: 0 and right:0, but this is just an hack cause i'm not able to reproduce that same issue you have.

Comment: @user3760661 Thanks for your time. I have this issue on a MAC with Safari and Chrome. Maybe this is just related to those MAC versions. I'll try your suggestions. Thanks. For now I solved it by simply using `float: right;` on the second element. But this of course only works for this special situation. :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked on Chrome and firefox with no issue, but in safari(mac), I found it.

Never figured it that before, thanks for that. My solution would be making the right box float right.

```
.box.half + .box.half {
   margin-right: 0;
   float:right;
}
```